# How to enqueue bootstrap without messing up wordpress own styles

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7

I'm adding bootstrap to wordpress admin part using

```
wp_register_style(
    'bootstrap-4.3.1',
    WP_VIP_CSS . 'bootstrap.min.css',
    [],
    '4.3.1',
    'all'
);
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-4.3.1' );
```

but when I refresh my page it will mess up.

> before adding bootstrap => 
>   [click see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BT0O.png)
>
> after adding bootstrap    => 
>   [click to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cckiX.png)

Comment: If your question about rtl support, you need a special plugin, for example https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl

Comment: [@Maksim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11251946/maksim) I already know these, but unfortunately I am using edited version [bootswatch.com/materia](https://bootswatch.com/materia/)

Comment: Pls specify this details in question

Comment: [@Maksim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11251946/maksim) what more do you want? please tell me.